# Cannot match any routes when I pass a token as parameter in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to reset user password, so I send them a token to their email. But when they click on the link, my route does not match. But when I use an alphabet or string, it will work.

My route:

```
{path: 'reset-password/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent}
```

The link sent is:

http://localhost:4200/reset-password/CfDJ8Nvsj8Jg1jxNk4c8WRGjJ/2eFMdiL/Gv0Bf8rsqQRLh6rHN9ZalNnJj1IkWiFuARfRnE/U4+qsytBh9yqW3Lp5syVdL1I/TrGmis/pJYKuyxJjrJWW/wpcuOy5Rdi8bMrmFlENnxNFtgNBGmJKommZOe0ffW+ZyUoaqqMftCwocfDIe1vesXuPqh7GuPXSiheLTBuXUA9kf9Qe1CVCrNfb859yYj5ug8sKTc5EzRiSZ5

Comment: Its probably because you the backslash in the token as well. Try to remove that just for testing purposes.

Comment: yes it was because of the slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to url encode the token before appending it to the link am sending to the user's email. on the Api, then i decoded it after it's sent back

string encodedToken = WebUtility.UrlEncode(token);